# django-rest-framework authentication: require key parameter in URL?

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I am working in Django 1.8 with the excellent django-rest-framework. I have a public RESTful API.

I would now like to start requiring a `key` GET parameter with this API, and disallowing any requests that do not have this parameter. I will allocate keys to users manually on request.

I have read through the [DRF Authentication documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#authentication), but I'm not sure there's anything that meets my use case. I find this strange, since my use case must be very common.

Token-based authentication requires the user to set an HTTP header. My typical API user is not sophisticated (Excel users who will be downloading CSVs), so I don't think I can ask them to do this.

I think Basic-Auth is what I need, but I'd much rather provide a simple URL-based key than a Django username and password (my app has no concept of users right now).

What is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a table which will contain all the keys that you issue to someone.

Example:

```
class RestApiKey(models.Model):
    api_key = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Next create a custom Permision class which will check for the api Key in the url before forwarding the request to the view like:

```
from rest_framework import permissions
from yourappname.models import RestApiKey

class OnlyAPIPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        try:
            api_key = request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('apikey', False)
            RestApiKey.objects.get(api_key=api_key)
            return True
        except:
            return False
```

So the request url has to be like http://yourdomain.com/?apikey=sgvwregwrgwg

Next in your views add the permission class:

```
class YourViewSet(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (OnlyAPIPermission,)
```

or if you are using function based views then do like:

```
@permission_classes((OnlyAPIPermission, ))
def example_view(request, format=None):
    . . .
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. Couple of notes for anyone else doing this: I had to import `permission_classes` in the view to get the decorator working. And I put the custom `OnlyAPIPermission` class in a new file in the application, then imported it in the views.