# Lightweight authentication method for non-technical users, that is also secure for an Ajax app?

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I have a public-facing REST API, which uses django-rest-framework and Django 1.8. The API currently requires no authentication. As part of the same web application, on the same domain, I have a JavaScript front-end which consumes the API.

My client now wants me to add some kind of authentication to this API. (The underlying goal is that we can keep track of who's using it - it's really social engineering, to encourage anyone who uses our data to cite our service.)

However, the target API users are not highly technical people - they're likely to be academics who will be using the API for data analysis, not web developers. So the more lightweight the authentication is better. I'm not sure our target users will cope with sending authentication requests, adding tokens in headers, etc.

What is the best kind of authentication to add to DRF that is (a) appropriately lightweight for our target user base, and (b) compatible with the need to authenticate my JavaScript front-end application in a way that doesn't expose our key to everyone?

My first thought was that I'd like to give users a key that they can add as a GET parameter ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33561226/194000)) - nice and simple for them. However, if I add key auth to the API, I'd then have to expose the key GET parameter in my JS application's XHR request, which is not ideal.

It's possible that our target audience wouldn't actually notice a key exposed in XHR requests, not being web developers. But I thought I'd ask if anyone can think of a better solution - very grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

[Token Authentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication)  is very simple to use but if your website doesn't use https the token can easily be stolen and used by attacker to perform api calls with it.

If authentication here is just for social engineering and doesn't matter if the token got leaked to a third party then I think its the way to go

Comment: Thanks. The site does use https. Am I right in thinking that for clients to authenticate, they'll need to add a token to the HTTP header? So they then wouldn't be able to explore responses in the browser, but would need to use the command line instead?

Comment: Also, won't users be able to inspect the headers of the Ajax request, even if the site uses HTTPS?

Comment: Yes you are right, if you want something browser friendly you should use session authentication instead.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#sessionauthentication

Comment: Thank you - but is it right that if I enable SessionAuth, users won't be able to query the API just with a GET key? (At least, I tried enabling it and that seemed to be the case.)

Comment: That really depends on what `permission_classes` you specify for your `viewset`
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/

    authentication_classes = (AllowAny,)

will essentially allow any person to use the api regardless of the authentication method you use